# Visual Studio Code ubuntu Terminal configuration to use npm

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, terminal, configuration

I'm using Visual Studio Code on ubuntu to develop Angular. I need to use npm in the terminal, but it doesn't work. This is what I see in the terminal:

```
sh-5.1$ id
uid=1000(zero) gid=1000(zero) groups=1000(zero),65534(nfsnobody)
sh-5.1$ npm start
sh: npm: command not found
sh-5.1$
```

Comment: what have you tried until now? also please provide your `settings.json` file, maybe you changed your settings by mistake (for ubuntu I believe it's located at `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`).

Comment: here is my settings.json: https://nc.rtyu.org/my_settings.json

Comment: can you access npm outside of vscode's integrated terminal? If so, please run `which npm` and reply with the output.

Comment: sh-5.1$ which npm
which: no npm in (/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/zero/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/node_modules/bin)

Comment: You probably uninstalled npm by accident, try reinstalling node.

Comment: The problem was that i'm using flatpack version of Visual Studio

Comment: You should've included that in your question, but anyway, add an answer to describe what you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that I'm using the Flatpack version of Visual Studio Code,
Solved it by uinstalling the Flatpack version and install the official version.